# ANR Broadcast of Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10 cmp=receiver.GcmBroadcastReceiver (has extras) }

Tags: android

I received an ANR log for my BroadcastReceiver, but why? `onReceive()` is just starting an `IntentService`, which should probably take some milliseconds, right? And the `IntenteService`'s `onHandleIntent()` is called in the background?

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    }
}
```

// GcmIntentService

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // executing db related stuff

        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
```

First part of the log:

> ----- pid 4006 at 2015-07-02 15:51:35 -----
>
> JNI: CheckJNI is off; workarounds are off; pins=0; globals=496
>
> DALVIK THREADS: (mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)
>
> "main" prio=5 tid=1 WAIT | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0
>   obj=0x4185eea0 self=0x41750030 | sysTid=4006 nice=-11 sched=0/0
>   cgrp=apps handle=1073869140 | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=10745
>   stm=2490 core=0 at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>   - waiting on <0x4185ef70> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=1 (main) at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205) at
>   sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325) at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157) at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:813)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:846)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1175)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:180)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:256)
>   at com.google.android.gms.analytics.bn.e((null):-1) at
>   com.google.android.gms.analytics.c.f((null):-1) at
>   com.google.android.gms.analytics.b.uncaughtException((null):-1) at
>   java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693) at
>   java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I've registered my receiver via manifest.xml:

```
<receiver
    android:name="receiver.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

        <category android:name="de.cwalz.receiver" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: You may wish to post the actual log entries.

Comment: It's waaay to long, I just posted the first part.

Comment: I guess I found the problem: Instead of calling `WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);` I should call `GCMBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);`, which will release the lock.

Comment: OK, I'm confused. I don't see anything in there that refers to any of your code, let alone your `BroadcastReceiver`. This looks like Play Services' analytics stuff is having a problem. "I should call GCMBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);" -- those should be equivalent, unless you have your own `completeWakefulIntent()` method.

Comment: Okay and if so, how to prevent these crashed if analytics is failing somehow?

Comment: Well, you probably can't. For starters, this may not even be your process. I still do not understand how you are drawing the connection between the LogCat lines in your question and your app.

Comment: allready told you in my answer (uncaughtException)

Comment: Seems to be a bug in Google Analytics for android: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/w_NLv91h0Pk. I will remove the line `tracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);` and will try it again.

Answer (score 1):

### When you use:

> Context#registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter)

- any application may send broadcasts to that registered receiver
- you can control who can send broadcasts to it through permissions
- **when you publish a receiver** in your application's manifest and specify intent-filters for it, **any other application can send broadcasts to it** regardless of the filters you specify.
- to prevent others from sending to it, make it unavailable to them with `android:exported="false"`.

in your case problem is in :

> uncaughtException  in com.google.android.gms.analytics
>
> (ANR is probably caused by deadlock - main is waiting for Thread:1205)

**SOLUTION:**

- filter onReceive() for not intended broadcasts,
- try catch exception
- if u cant try Ovverride some methods

Comment: did u check who is broadcasting to your broadcast  receiver ?

Comment: No, but is this relevant for my initial question? Well, actually I do with the `permission:`-element.

Comment: you giving keys to your home everyone ?

Comment: Okay, I've added `android:exported="false"` to my receivers to prevent foreign apps to access these receivers. I guess I found the problem, check comments in question.